# SQL Count each occurence of words separated by comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply

I have a column in a table with words separated by comma. I need to count each occurence of each word
My column looks like : ('a, b, c'), ('a, b, d'), ('b, c, d'), ('a'), ('a, c');
(fiddle at the bottom)

Here is what I get :

```
MyCol        Count
-----------------
a           1
a, b, c     3
a, b, d     3
a, c        2
b, c, d     3
```

But here is what I expect

```
MyCol    Count
-------------
a        4
b        3
c        3
d        2
```

Here is what I've done so far :

```
select MyCol, COUNT(*)
from Test
cross apply string_split(MyCol, ',')
group by MyCol
```

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e52e/3

Please note the words are separated by a comma AND a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong column. Simply use the `[value]` column (returned from the `STRING_SPLIT()` call) and remove the space characters (using `TRIM()` for SQL Server 2017+ or `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` for earlier versions):

```
SELECT TRIM(s.[value]) AS [value], COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM Test t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.MyCol, ',') s
GROUP BY TRIM(s.[value])
ORDER BY TRIM(s.[value])
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. I didn't understand why "value" was so important

Comment: I'd also suggest naming the column such as with `AS s(word)` or similar, so it's clear where the expression comes from.

Answer (score 1):

```
select value,count(*)cntt
from Test
cross apply string_split(MyCol,',')
group by value
order by value;
```

Comment: Separated by comma *and* space. Thus, need `trim(value)`

Answer (score 1):

remove white space by using `REPLACE`  and then use `Subquery`

```
select MyCol,count(MyCol) as Count from(
select  
REPLACE (value, ' ', '' ) as MyCol
--TRIM(value) as MyCol -- both TRIM and REPLACE are equivalent 
----comment one of them
from test
cross apply string_split(MyCol, ',')) b
group by MyCol
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e52e/12)

Comment: Why not use TRIM()?

Comment: yeah it can be use thanks for your mention.

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
select MyCol, 1 + LEN(MyCol) - LEN(REPLACE(MyCol, ',', '')) AS NUM
from Test
```